# Can I simulate a HW device with HW address using a kernel module? (edit: virtual address that will rout to my module)

Tags: linux-kernel

I need to test how our production Linux module handles HW errors.
the driver I'm testing should not be changed except may be the HW address that the driver uses to talk to the HW.

---

I want to write a kernel module that intercepts reads/writes to the HW and if needed change them, it also needs to handle the interrupt, but that i know how to do.

---

can I simulate a HW address for the production driver to load on and reads/writes will be routed to my driver and i will forward to HW or do i need specific HW for this?

---

edit: since i can override the mmap of the driver i'm testing, can i create a virtual address in kernel space that redirects reads/writes to my module?

Comment: Look at the `mmiotracer` functionality (available only for x86).

Comment: Thanks but I'm working on arm cortex-a

Answer (score 0):

Apparently since our driver is supposed to work on different hardware it has "hardware abstraction layer" that the user should implement and all access to the hw are trow this layer. I will add error insertion there.
If anybody still has a way please let me know regardless .
Btw I'm working on arm processors .